# bulk letter with datatool: how to handle linebreak csv-field

Tags: datatool

I'm generating a bulk letter using datatool. Therefore I import my data from an external csv-file using the following syntax:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{dinbrief}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[separator=;]{datatool}
\newrobustcmd{\companyrobust}{\parbox[b]{7.5cm}{\raggedright\company}}
\begin{document}
\inputencoding{latin1}
\DTLloadrawdb{addr}{list.csv} % open database
\inputencoding{utf8}
\DTLforeach{addr}{
  \company=company,
  \firstname=firstname,
  \surname=surname%
}{ % start bulk letter
\begin{letter}{\companyrobust\\\firstname\ \surname}
\subject{\textbf{test}}
\opening{Dear Mr. \surname,}
nothing
\closing{regards}
\end{letter}
}
\end{document}
```

the corresponding list.csv is the following:

```
company;firstname;surname
Microsoft Software;Bill;Gates
```

This was working for me for quite a while but now I have the problem that there is a company in my list which has a linebreak in its name. For example I want to put "Software" in a new line. I tried using `\\`, `\linebreak` and `\newline` but I it did not work and I could not figure out how to succeed. How can I realize a defined line break within a field of the csv-file?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) document showing how you're using the data in the document (for example, are you just using the standard `letter` class with the `letter` environment), and also a short sample csv file with an example entry that needs a line break.

Comment: I extended my question with a complete MWE

Comment: Is this list of `company` values created automatically? In your setup you could use `Microsoft\DTLpar Software` and avoid using a line-break in the actual CSV.

Comment: Yes, it is created automatically. But it wouldn't be a problem to insert the \DTLpar at the appropriate points in the csv file. However, if I insert it, latex gives me an error and does not compile.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: The error message I get is `Paragraph ended before \@sDTLnewdbentry was complete.` A second error is then `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` and then three times the error `Package datatool Error: Can't assign \company : there is no key ´company' in data base ´addr'.` with all different columns of the csv-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to include LaTeX commands in your csv file, you can't use `\DTLloadrawdb`. If you switch to `\DTLloaddb` instead, your example works fine with `\DTLpar`.

list.csv:

```
company;firstname;surname
Microsoft\DTLpar Software;Bill;Gates
```

Test file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{dinbrief}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[separator=;]{datatool}
\newrobustcmd{\companyrobust}{\parbox[b]{7.5cm}{\raggedright\company}}
\begin{document}
\inputencoding{latin1}
\DTLloaddb{addr}{list.csv} % open database
\inputencoding{utf8}
\DTLforeach{addr}{
  \company=company,
  \firstname=firstname,
  \surname=surname%
}{ % start bulk letter
\begin{letter}{\companyrobust\\\firstname\ \surname}
\subject{\textbf{test}}
\opening{Dear Mr. \surname,}
nothing
\closing{regards}
\end{letter}
}
\end{document}
```